# Interaction Array List and Lucky Wheel

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello I am new to programming

I am using this library https://github.com/thanhniencung/LuckyWheel

How to use user-created data in the Wheel?

`ArrayList<String> Item = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import rubikstudio.library.LuckyWheelView;
import rubikstudio.library.model.LuckyItem;

public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_wheel);

        ArrayList<String> Item = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");


        LuckyWheelView luckyWheelView = findViewById(R.id.wheel);
        List<LuckyItem> data = new ArrayList<LuckyItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            LuckyItem luckyItem = new LuckyItem();
            luckyItem.secondaryText = "Item"+i;
            data.add(luckyItem);
        }

        luckyWheelView.setData(data);
        luckyWheelView.setRound(getRandomRound());
        luckyWheelView.setLuckyWheelBackgrouldColor(R.array.color_wheel);

        Button Button = findViewById(R.id.play);
        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int index = getRandomIndex();
                luckyWheelView.startLuckyWheelWithTargetIndex(index);
            }
        });
        luckyWheelView.setLuckyRoundItemSelectedListener(new LuckyWheelView.LuckyRoundItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void LuckyRoundItemSelected(int index) {
                if (index == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 2){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 3){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 4){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 5){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 6){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 7){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 8){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 9){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 10){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (index == 11){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(index).secondaryText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private int getRandomRound() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(5) + 8;
    }

    private int getRandomIndex() {
        int[] ind = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
        int rand = new Random().nextInt(ind.length);
        return ind[rand];
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can't, LuckyWheel Library only accepts data of type `LuckyItem` You should use a converter to convert your custom data to `LuckyItem`

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.